# Image in Google Sheets moves when sheet is embedded in Google Sites

Tags: image, google-sheets, google-sites

I'm setting up a heat map in Sheets which tracks maintenance work orders for an apartment complex. I have an image of the complex that I adjusted to being 50% transparent so you can see through it to the cells underneath. The cells underneath have formulas that calculate off a database. I apply conditional formatting to these cells so that as more maintenance techs log work orders, the resulting heat map changes. The problem I'm having is that the image shifts in relation to the underlying cells when I embed the Sheet into Google Sites. The heat map is then no longer aligned properly.

I tried to insert the image as both a shape and a picture and neither stopped the issue from happening. I also tried purposely off-setting the image in Sheets thinking that it would then be aligned better when embedded into Sites, but that doesn't work either.

The expected result when embedding the Sheet into Sites is for the image to stay fixed in relation to the underlying cells. The actual result is the image shifts which then renders the underlying heat map unusable. Any thoughts on how to prevent this from happening? Thanks!

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue, and failed immediately. When you say "adjusted to 50% transparent" can you explain what you mean? I can't see any option within Sheets to do this, and even when I manipulated a jpeg file to 50% transparency (via Gimp) and inserted it into a Sheet, I can't see through it.

Providing a publicly accessible link to a Sheet demonstrating the problem may help. Either that or a step-by-step guide to how to reproduce your problem.